# Custom tool tip for multiple contour plots on same page using plotly.js is not working properly

Tags: javascript, plotly

Here is sample code (https://jsfiddle.net/meb4wnLd/6/):

```js
var x =[10,30,150,600,1200,1800];
var y = [-25,-7,10,25,35];
var z= [
     [250, 165, 91, 69, 0,0],
          [250,250,159,79,41,27],
          [250,250,192,82,42,28],
          [250,250,192,84,42,28],
          [250,250,195,84,42,28]
];
var z1= [
     [240, 155, 91, 59, 0,0],
          [240,240,149,59,31,17],
          [240,240,182,72,32,17],
          [240,240,182,74,32,17],
          [240,240,185,74,32,17]
];
var data = [ {
 x : x,
  y : y,
  z: z,
  type: 'contour', 
  autocontour: true,
  connectgaps: true,
  contours: {
   coloring: 'heatmap',   
    showlabels: true,
    labelfont: {
      family: 'Raleway',
      size: 12,
      color: 'white',
    }
    },
    colorbar:{ 
      title:"zAxisData",
      titleside: 'right',
      titlefont: {
        size: 14,
        family: 'Arial, sans-serif'
      }
    }  
}];
var data1 = [ {
 x : x,
  y : y,
  z: z1,
  type: 'contour', 
  autocontour: true,
  connectgaps: true,
  contours: {
   coloring: 'heatmap',   
    showlabels: true,
    labelfont: {
      family: 'Raleway',
      size: 12,
      color: 'white',
    }
    },
    colorbar:{ 
      title:"zAxisData",
      titleside: 'right',
      titlefont: {
        size: 14,
        family: 'Arial, sans-serif'
      }
    }  
}];
var layout ={  
        xaxis: {
          title: "xAxisData", //set x axis label
          type: 'category',                    
          anchor: 'yaxis',
          titlefont: {
            family: 'Courier New, monospace',
            size: 18,
            color: '#7f7f7f'
          }
        },
        yaxis: {
          title: "yAxisData", //set y axis label
          type :'category',                    
          anchor: 'xaxis',
          titlefont: {
            family: 'Courier New, monospace',
            size: 18,
            color: '#7f7f7f'
          }
        },
        hovermode:'closest',
      };
      
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
Plotly.newPlot('myDiv1', data1, layout);

var div = Plotly.d3.select('body').append("div")                  .attr("class", "tooltip-d3")    
          .style("opacity", 1);
var myPlot = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var myPlot1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');

  myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(eventdata){           
            //console.log(divName);
                console.log(eventdata);
              var points = eventdata.points[0];                           
              
              var tooltip ="<table>";
                          
              tooltip = tooltip + "<tr><td>"+points.x+"</td><td>"+points.y+"</td></tr><tr><td>"+points.z+"</td><td></td></tr></table>";

              var x = points.xaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[1]) + points.xaxis._offset;
                var y = points.yaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[0]) + points.yaxis._offset;
            
                div.transition()  
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", 1);  
                div.html(tooltip)                   
                .style("left", x +"px")  
                .style("top", (y+70) + "px");                                                        
        }, false);

        myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
                  div.transition()  
                        .duration(500)  
                        .style("opacity", 0); 
              },false);
 
 //Hover code for second graphs             
 myPlot1.on('plotly_hover', function(eventdata){           
            //console.log(divName);
                console.log(eventdata);
              var points = eventdata.points[0];                           
              
              var tooltip ="<table>";
                          
              tooltip = tooltip + "<tr><td>"+points.x+"</td><td>"+points.y+"</td></tr><tr><td>"+points.z+"</td><td></td></tr></table>";

              var x = points.xaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[1]) + points.xaxis._offset;
                var y = points.yaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[0]) + points.yaxis._offset;
            
                div.transition()  
                .duration(200)  
                .style("opacity", 1);  
                div.html(tooltip)                   
                .style("left", x +"px")  
                .style("top", (y+70) + "px");                                                        
        }, false);

        myPlot1.on('plotly_unhover', function(data){
                  div.transition()  
                        .duration(500)  
                        .style("opacity", 0); 
              },false);
```

```css
.tooltip-d3 { 
    position: absolute;   
    text-align: center;   
    min-width: 175px;      
    min-height: 150;     
    padding: 2px;    
    font-size: 8px;  
    background : #fff; 
    border: 1px solid #000;  
    border-radius: 8px;   
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 9999;   
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">

</div>
<div id="myDiv1" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">

</div>
```

I am creating multiple contour plots on same page and trying to create custom tool tip for contour plots by handling 'plotly_hover' event (As mentioned here https://community.plot.ly/t/how-to-customize-plotly-tooltip/332/2). But on hovering on second graph shows custom tool tip on first graph.
Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: Your code should be included into question body, not as external link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, seems there is a lot wrong with it, the fundamental problem is that, you are attaching the `tooltip` to the `body` tag instead of the individual plots, hence even if we hover over the second graph, the tool tip will appear relative to the body tag, hence we find it in the same location, the solution for this is to add the tooltip to the individual charts.

```
var tooltip1 = Plotly.d3.select('#myDiv .svg-container').append("div").attr("class", "tooltip-d3")
  .style("opacity", 1);
var tooltip2 = Plotly.d3.select('#myDiv1 .svg-container').append("div").attr("class", "tooltip-d3")
  .style("opacity", 1);
```

We can create two new div's using the above code for each of the graphs, these will contains the respective tooltips.

```
myPlot.on('plotly_hover', function(eventdata) {
  //console.log(divName);
  console.log(eventdata);
  var points = eventdata.points[0];

  var tooltip = "<table>";

  tooltip = tooltip + "<tr><td>" + points.x + "</td><td>" + points.y + "</td></tr><tr><td>" + points.z + "</td><td></td></tr></table>";

  var x = points.xaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[1]) + points.xaxis._offset;
  var y = points.yaxis.l2p(points.pointNumber[0]) + points.yaxis._offset;

  tooltip1.transition()
    .duration(200)
    .style("opacity", 1);
  tooltip1.html(tooltip)
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("left", x + "px")
    .style("top", (y + 70) + "px");
}, false);

myPlot.on('plotly_unhover', function(data) {
  tooltip1.transition()
    .duration(500)
    .style("opacity", 0);
}, false);
```

Then using the above code, we can show/hide the respective tooltips.

Please study my solution and let me know if there is any difficulty in understanding.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

```
Note: SO Snippet seems to hang when I use the code, hence going with JSFiddle!
```